# ng-view height 100% overflow

Tags: html, css, angularjs

I’m building an app in angularjs and my index page has a ng-view where all content is injected with ui-router:

```
<header>
    <nav class="navbar">
        //navbar content here
    </nav
</header>

<div ng-view></div>
```

The problem here is that my home page needs to have 100% height - it is injected in ng-view, therefore I'm setting ng-view’s height to 100%. 
Now, when every other ng-view page is rendered I have a vertical overflow on the page - height of the ng-view (100%) plus whatever is the menu’s height, as it is outside of ng-view.

[Here is a plunker example](http://embed.plnkr.co/c4b5W7j54OCAIGcchytv/preview)

How can I fix this?

---

Even though I accepted the answer, I still had the problem, because my home page needed to have 100% height, but css calc would cut the specified percentage out and overflow-y hidden wouldn't let me scroll down. I ended up using Viewport Percentage - setting the ng-view div to 100vh in my css fixed the problem for me.

```
height: 100vh;
```

Comment: could you reproduce this problem with plunkr or fiddle>?

Comment: I added a plunker example

Comment: If the problem is the scrollbar, you can always add `overflow-y: hidden` to the body: http://plnkr.co/edit/Sv025dE2JsuFCfUjwZuJ?p=preview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you really care about older browsers you can use javascript

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/d22ecnxm/1/))

```js
height = window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight;
document.getElementById("body").style.height = height - 50 + "px";
```

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 150, 250);
  color: #fff;
}
.body {
  background-color: rgb(40, 140, 240);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  Hello World
</div>
<div class="body" id="body">
  Foo Bar!
</div>
```

If you don't really care about older browsers but you don't want to be too new, you can use the css flexbox method with `display:flex` and `flex-flow:column` on the container, then set the height of the top bar to a static height and `height:100%` and `overflow:auto` to the bottom section

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ny597mfr/1/)) ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox))

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.menu {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 150, 250);
  color: #fff;
}
.body {
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgb(40, 140, 240);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  Hello World
</div>
<div class="body">
  Foo Bar!
</div>
```

If you don't care about old browsers at all and you like new things you can use CSS3's calc() function.

([Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/humbleRumble/ovx8b17z/)) ([caniuse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc))

```css
html,
body {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
.menu {
  line-height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(50, 150, 250);
  color: #fff;
}
.body {
  height: calc(100% - 50px);
  background-color: rgb(40, 140, 240);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<div class="menu">
  Hello World
</div>
<div class="body">
  Foo Bar!
</div>
```